# Is there a way to know which GTK version is installed using the command line?

Tags: command-line, gtk, versions

Is there a way to know which GTK version is installed using the command line?

I am working on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: `dpkg -l "*gtk*" | grep ii`

Comment: @Anonymous: that returns 50 lines on my Debian system.

Comment: @ZayneSHalsall try the answer below that have  this sign

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0` (optionally pipe to `grep Installed`)

or

`dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0`

Comment: The grep is localized, so for french users you may have to type ` | grep Installé`

Comment: rather than assuming the major version to get the minor version, one can first run something like: `dpkg --get-selections | grep 'libgtk.*bin'` which today will likely show gtk2, gtk3, and gtk4, then you can pass those to `dpkg -l`, for example, `dpkg -l libgtk2.0-bin libgtk-3-bin libgtk-4-bin`

Comment: @michael, you can also use that with dpkg-query as in `dpkg-query -W libgtk*bin`

Comment: @randyman99 - This is the most useful command.

Answer (score 9):

--get-selections will show you the installed packages

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep gtk
```

Comment: This is the ONLY answer of all the terrible answers that actually makes sense. And guess what, on my 22.04 there are THREE GTK versions installed. `libgtk2.0-bin libgtk-3-bin libgtk-4-bin` among many other GTK packages.

Comment: This just gives a list of packages that contain "gtk" in their name.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
```

This will give info for both GTK 2 and 3.

Comment: Too bad still not gtk 4.0

Comment: Well with this shitty you never know if you have GTK 4 installed because it does not ask for it. (And yes I realize this question is 10 years old, with makes this answer now BAD)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager:
   [image]
2. Under "Quick filter" enter "libgtk-3".
3. Gtk3 libraries are contained in "libgtk-3-0". You may want to select it for convenience. Your installed version appears in the column "Installed version".
   If you need additional information press the button "Properties".

Answer (score 2):

Try: `dpkg-query -W libgtk-3-bin`

```
# Gives version as 3.10.8, separated on the left by a tab, and on the right by a ~
$ dpkg-query -W libgtk-3-bin
libgtk-3-bin    3.10.8~8+qiana

# An associated package also gives the package architecture [for me]
$ dpkg-query -W libgtk-3-0
libgtk-3-0:amd64    3.10.8~8+qiana
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands

```bash
gtk-launch  --version
gtk3-launch --version
gtk4-launch --version
```