# What is GTK to Gnome shell and unity

Tags: unity, gnome, gtk

Can someone tell me what exactly is GTK, Genome shell, and unity in between all of those.

I might sound stupid but can someone tell me how to take advantage of any of these I am using and which one am I using.

Currently using ubuntu 13.10

Thanks in advace,

Quantum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What is GTK

At its simplest level - GTK is a graphical toolkit i.e. a series of libraries and a known Application Programming Interface (API) to allow developers to create applications using these predefined libraries of code.

By using such a toolkit, applications have a consistent look and feel - various graphical components will behave in a similar manner

### Gnome-Shell & Unity

At their simplest level - Gnome-Shell & Unity are similarly an "application" that uses GTK to give them their look-and-feel.

I'm being highly simplistic - Gnome-Shell & Unity are complex beasts using many programming technologies, window managers etc.  They are in-fact many-many individual "applications" pulled together to provide a User Interface you interact with.

I'm counting here scripts of various sorts (python/bash etc), individual applications built in C/C++/Python/Javascript etc etc.

### Conclusions

You dont need to do anything to "take advantage" unless you are yourself an aspiring developer - you just need to be aware of the underlying technologies - GTK is just one of many.

---

### Resources:

- [How to know my GTK version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78377/how-to-know-my-gtk-version)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK
- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/gtk-getting-started.html
- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell
- https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/

Comment: With bash on windows I'm starting to research GTK within WSL. Any pointers?