# how to find system parts version numbers?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, libreoffice, gtk, versions

LibreOffice help recommends me to install a higher version of LibreOffice than I can get from the Ubuntu Software Center. I can do it by direct installing from *.deb files.
I know most of required system properties, their versions are much higher than required. I hope that it applies also for the other ones, but **the lower LibreOffice version in the Ubuntu Software Center may be due to such a discrepancy. If it is so, please answer this long question summarily.**

For installing I need to see if my Ubuntu 12.04 system has

- gtk version 2.10.4 or higher [According to [How to know my GTK version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78377/how-to-know-my-gtk-version/88111#88111) I have got

  ```
  user@CPU:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep gtk
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk   install
  appmenu-gtk                  install
  appmenu-gtk3                 install
  apport-gtk                   install
  bzr-gtk                      install
  gir1.2-dbusmenu-gtk-0.4      install
  gir1.2-gtk-2.0               install
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0               install
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0         install
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 install
  gtk2-engines                 install
  gtk2-engines-murrine         install
  gtk3-engines-unico           install
  ibus-gtk                     install
  ibus-gtk3                    install
  jockey-gtk                   install
  libavahi-ui-gtk3-0           install
  libcanberra-gtk-module       install
  libcanberra-gtk0             install
  libcanberra-gtk3-0           install
  libcanberra-gtk3-module      install
  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4           install
  libdbusmenu-gtk4             install
  libgdu-gtk0                  install
  libgtk-3-0                   install
  libgtk-3-bin                 install
  libgtk-3-common              install
  libgtk2-perl                 install
  libgtk2.0-0                  install
  libgtk2.0-bin                install
  libgtk2.0-common             install
  libgtkhtml-4.0-0             install
  libgtkhtml-4.0-common        install
  libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0      install
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a            install
  libgtkmm-3.0-1               install
  libgtksourceview-3.0-0       install
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common  install
  libgtkspell-3-0              install
  libgwibber-gtk2              install
  libindicate-gtk3             install
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0   install
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0   install
  libnm-gtk-common             install
  libnm-gtk0                   install
  libreoffice-gtk              install
  libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni       install
  libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni         install
  libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni       install
  libswt-gtk-3-java            install
  libswt-gtk-3-jni             install
  libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni      install
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0           install
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common      install
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0           install
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-common      install
  libwmf0.2-7-gtk              install
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets install
  python-gtk2                  install
  software-properties-gtk      install
  transmission-gtk             install
  ubuntu-sso-client-gtk        install
  usb-creator-gtk              install
  xdg-user-dirs-gtk            install
  user@CPU:~$
  ```

  ];
- glibc2 version 2.5 or higher [

  ```
  user@CPU:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep glibc2
  user@CPU:~$
  ```

  ];
- Gnome 2.16 or higher, with the gail 1.8.6 and the at-spi 1.7 packages (required for support for assistive technology [AT] tools), or another compatible GUI (such as KDE, among others) - [by my System Monitor: GNOME 3.4.2,

  ```
  user@CPU:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep gail
  libgail-3-0                  install
  libgail-common               install
  libgail18                    install
  user@CPU:~$
  user@CPU:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep at-spi
  at-spi2-core                 install
  qt-at-spi                    install
  user@CPU:~$
  ```

  ]. Which of the numbers are relevant for the particular part of my system? If none, how to find the required ones? Is glibc2 relevant for the purpose?
- 'A recent version of Java Runtime Environment (JRE). How can I find which version is installed?

  **Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

You can run `dpkg -l | grep package_name` to get its version. It's not always clear what the exact name is, so here are some suggestions for 12.04:

```
ii  libgtk2.0-0      2.24.10-0ubuntu6.1      GTK+ graphical user interface library

ii  libglib2.0-0     2.32.4-0ubuntu1         GLib library of C routines

ii  libc-bin         2.15-0ubuntu10.5        Embedded GNU C Library: Binaries
```

For java, please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150057/how-can-i-tell-what-version-of-java-i-have-installed).

Alternatively, just search http://packages.ubuntu.com.